# Accounting for Time in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, time

I have a log of times for 2 periods (1 & 2) in a data frame. I need to account for the time accumulated for each person based on a third column 'in' vs 'out'. I then need to create an additional column to track the sum of accumulated time for both periods.

```
Period   Time        Subs
  1      10:00      'Peter in'
  1        .    
  1        .     
  1       8:00      'Peter out' #In this period he has accumulated 2 minutes
  2      10:00      'Peter in'
  2        .
  2       2:00      'Peter out' #In this period he has accumulated 8 minutes
```

I know I need to use an if and ifelse statement but I'm not sure how to start. I started and stopped learning R and now I'm trying to pick back up where I left off.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how your data is formatted, of course. if you have something like

```
df <- data.frame(Period=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2), Time=c("10:00",NA,NA,"8:00","10:00",NA,"2:00"))

> df
  Period  Time
1      1 10:00
2      1  <NA>
3      1  <NA>
4      1  8:00
5      2 10:00
6      2  <NA>
7      2  2:00
```

If the `Time` variable is formatted as character, you can strip out the minutes column like so:

```
df$Min <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Time), ":"), "[[", 1))

> df
  Period  Time Min
1      1 10:00  10
2      1  <NA>  NA
3      1  <NA>  NA
4      1  8:00   8
5      2 10:00  10
6      2  <NA>  NA
7      2  2:00   2
```

This is much easier if you can have the `Min` column already as numeric!

Then, an easy way to return the total time accumulated for each period is the `diff` of the `range` for each period, within a `tapply()` call.

```
tapply(df$Min, df$Period, function(x) diff(range(x, na.rm=T)))
1 2 
2 8
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to give it a try. I'll let you know how it goes, but so far it looks like that's exactly what I needed. Thanks for taking the time to help @MattTyers!